# convert_datetimefield_value() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given using django with mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.6, djongo

Django Admin login page, I am using mongodb for django, after that only I got error

mongodb configure:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'django-mongo-db',
    }
}

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhLAu.png)

Comment: any code is there

Comment: please click the link, because I am not wrote any codes. I just configure mongodb that's it

Comment: Post the code that causes this and *copy* the traceback, instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'django-mongo-db',
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You are using `djongo` as your backend engine, the requirement of `djongo` is `Django==2.1.2`. Please install the same as -

```
pip install django==2.1.2
```

I have faced this error in the past. Doing this resolved it.